# Bidirectional communication with 'docker exec -it bash <container_id>' using docker-py

Tags: python, bash, docker, dockerpy

I can't seem to figure out how to enable async i/o with a container shell session using docker-py SDK. What I am essentially trying to achieve is to have a working equivalent of `docker exec -it bash $container_id` in docker-py.

Obviously, stdout poses no problems. It's just that there is no (glaringly obvious) way to actually write to stdin to interact with the running container's shell. Is that really so?

```
cmd = "bash"
cli = docker.DockerClient()
cli.containers.get(container_id)
socket = cli.exec_run(cmd, stdin=True, socket=True)
socket.writable() # => False
```

I also tried running `'bin/bash -c "export TERM=xterm; exec bash"` as a cmd and adding `tty` flag to exec_run. Needless to say, to no avail.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I think you switched the arguments in your question and meant to say `docker exec -it $container_id bash` ?